Problem figuring out how to adjust allowed response size using Mistral-Nemo with Ollama in a RAG setup
So I get good results, except I've noticed that if I request results text-only they are much more verbose than if I tell Ollama " response must be formatted as HTML" It's almost like the formatting characters count against some token limit.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance!
I have num_ctx adjusted to 16384, but from what I've read that really only adjusts context size, or basically input size. I feel like I'm either misunderstanding something, or missing something. I can't find any settings related to response size. I don't want to force a response size and end up with hallucinations, but the disparity between with/without HTML formatting is weird to me.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
